# How to move a document in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Can someone help me how to rename, move or update document or collection names in Cloud Firestore?

Also is there anyway that I can access my Cloud Firestore to update my collections or documents from terminal or any application?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Actually there is no `move` method that allows you to simply move a document from a location to another. You need to create one. For moving a document from a location to another, I suggest you use the following method:

```
public void moveFirestoreDocument(DocumentReference fromPath, final DocumentReference toPath) {
    fromPath.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document != null) {
                    toPath.set(document.getData())
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully written!");
                                fromPath.delete()
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                            Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully deleted!");
                                        }
                                })
                                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                            Log.w(TAG, "Error deleting document", e);
                                        }
                                });
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "Error writing document", e);
                            }
                        });
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

In which `fromPath` is the location of the document that you want to be moved and `toPath` is the location in which you want to move the document.

The flow is as follows:

> 1. **`Get`** the document from **`fromPath`** location.
> 2. **`Write`** the document to **`toPath`** location.
> 3. **`Delete`** the document from **`fromPath`** location.

That's it!

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you please explain how to move collection?

Comment: In the same way as documents. `fromPath` instead of pointing to a document location needs to point to a collection location.

Comment: @AlexMamo  Would the above work if the document has subcollection?

Comment: @Snake It will move only the documents. It won't move the subcollections if the document has subcollections.

Comment: Thank you Alex. Makes sense based on your other post

Comment: Can you do this in Python? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60450104/how-to-copy-all-the-documents-from-one-collection-to-another-in-google-firestore

Comment: @johnrao07 Try to implement it and if you find hard times in doing that, post a question here in StackOverflow so we can tale a look at it.

Comment: I would have used a transaction.  In case the delete fails, you're not stuck with a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another variation for getting a collection under a new name, it includes:

1. Ability to retain original ID values
2. Option to update field names

---

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        FirestoreAdmin.copyCollection(
            'blog_posts',
            'posts'
        );

    });
```

=====

```
var FirestoreAdmin = {

    // to copy changes back into original collection
    // 1. comment out these fields
    // 2. make the same call but flip the fromName and toName 
    previousFieldName: 'color',
    newFieldName: 'theme_id',

    copyCollection: function (fromName, toName) {

        FirestoreAdmin.getFromData(
            fromName,
            function (querySnapshot, error) {

                if (ObjectUtil.isDefined(error)) {

                    var toastMsg = 'Unexpected error while loading list: ' + StringUtil.toStr(error);
                    Toaster.top(toastMsg);
                    return;
                }

                var db = firebase.firestore();

                querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {

                    var docId = doc.id;
                    Logr.debug('docId: ' + docId);

                    var data = doc.data();
                    if (FirestoreAdmin.newFieldName != null) {

                        data[FirestoreAdmin.newFieldName] = data[FirestoreAdmin.previousFieldName];
                        delete data[FirestoreAdmin.previousFieldName];
                    }

                    Logr.debug('data: ' + StringUtil.toStr(data));

                    FirestoreAdmin.writeToData(toName, docId, data)
                });
            }
        );
    },

    getFromData: function (fromName, onFromDataReadyFunc) {

        var db = firebase.firestore();

        var fromRef = db.collection(fromName);
        fromRef
            .get()
            .then(function (querySnapshot) {

                onFromDataReadyFunc(querySnapshot);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {

                onFromDataReadyFunc(null, error);
                console.log('Error getting documents: ', error);
            });
    },

    writeToData: function (toName, docId, data) {

        var db = firebase.firestore();
        var toRef = db.collection(toName);

        toRef
            .doc(docId)
            .set(data)
            .then(function () {
                console.log('Document set success');
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.error('Error adding document: ', error);
            });

    }

}
```

=====

Here's the previous answer where the items are added under new IDs

```
        toRef
            .add(doc.data())
            .then(function (docRef) {
                console.log('Document written with ID: ', docRef.id);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.error('Error adding document: ', error);
            });
```

Comment: Since the OP's question has the [tag:android] tag, looks like your answer does not answer his/her question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue in Swift. You retrieve info from the document, put it into a new document in new location, delete old document.
Code looks like this:

```
    let sourceColRef = self.db.collection("/Users/users/Collection/")
    colRef.document("oldDocument").addSnapshotListener { (documentSnapshot, error) in
                if let error = error {
                            print(error)
                        } else {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            if let document = documentSnapshot?.data() {
                                
                                let field1 = document["Field 1"] as? String // or Int, or whatever you have)
                                let field2 = document["Field 2"] as? String
                                let field3 = document["Field 3"] as? String
                                
                                
                  let newDocRef = db.document("/Users/users/NewCollection/newDocument")
                                newDocRef.setData([
                                        "Field 1" : field1!,
                                        "Field 1" : field2!,
                                        "Field 1" : field3!,
                                        
                                ])
                            }
                          }
                        }
                    }
            
            sourceColRef.document("oldDocument").delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

// Try running a batch with deleting from source and setting on destination.

```
public void moveDocument(final DocumentReference source,
                         final DocumentReference dest) {
    source.get().addOnSuccessListener(doc -> {
        if (doc.getData() != null) {
            runOnBatch(b -> {
                b.set(source, doc.getData());
                b.delete(dest);
            });
        }
    });
}


public void runOnBatch(Consumer<WriteBatch> supplier) {
    final WriteBatch batch = myRef.batch();

    supplier.accept(batch);

    batch.commit()
            .addOnFailureListener(this::handleFailure)
            .addOnSuccessListener(task -> logSuccess(format("Batch optession success")));
}
```