# How to move a subcollection on CloudFirestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We are planning to implement a virtual filesystem using Google Firestore.

The idea of subcollections is nice because it allows us to model our data in terms of a folder hierarchy, like so: `/folders/folderA/entities/folderB/entities/fileX`

Much like an actual filesystem, we'd like to handle cross-folder moves, such as moving nested subfolder `folderB` from parent `folderA` to parent `folderC`. Indeed, it will often be the case that the folder we want to move may themselves contain their own subcollections of files and folders an arbitrary K levels deep.

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47244403/how-to-move-a-document-in-cloud-firestore#comment85422117_47263246) suggests that moving a document will not automagically move its associated subcollections. Similarly, [deleting a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data) will forego deleting its underlying subcollections, leaving them as orphans. It seems like the only way to move a folder (and its entities) from one parent to another would be through a recursive clone + delete strategy, which may be difficult to accomplish reliably and transactionally if its sub-entities are massive.

The alternative is to abandon using subcollections and store all folders at the root instead, using a document field like `parent_id` to point to other docs within the flat collection. This [shouldn't impact querying speeds](https://youtu.be/o7d5Zeic63s?t=459) due to Firestore's aggressive indexing, **but we've been unable to reproduce this claim locally; i.e., querying via subcollections is vastly more performant as the total # of documents increase in the DB, versus storing everything at the top level.** A reproducible repo is available [here](https://github.com/kevinmichaelchen/firestore-example). Note that the repo uses a local emulator instance, as opposed to an actual Firestore server.

Any advice would be very helpful!

Comment: I wouldn't interpret the performance of the local emulator to be anything like the cloud hosted service.  The local emulator runs on a single machine, and the actual service is massively scalable on many machines in Google cloud infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson! We will use the real cloud hosted service to continue our experiment / POC and see if there is a real difference in query times

Comment: @robinnnnn can you share how your server-side performance tests worked out?