# Copy a document into a new collection in firestore using cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

Path 1 - Match_Creator/cricket/matchList;
Path 2 - Match_Creator/cricket/completedMatchList;
I have a collection called matchList (Path 1) In which i am having a doc called c434108.
Now I want to move this doc(c434108) to Path 2;

```
/* eslint-disable promise/catch-or-return */
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const { db } = require("./db/index");

const createCompletedMatchListDoc = (request, response) => {
  completedMatchDocsData();
};

function completedMatchDocsData() {
  createNewCompletedMatchDocs()
 }

function getOldCompletedMatchDocs(){

  var completedMatchesRef = db
  .collection("Match_Creator")
  .doc("cricket")
  .collection("matchList");

  var completedMatchDocData;
  var completedMatchDataArr = [];

return new Promise(resolve => {
    let query = completedMatchesRef
      .where("status", "==", "live")
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line promise/always-return
        if (snapshot.empty) {
          console.log("No matching documents.");
          return;
        }

        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          completedMatchDocData = doc.data();     
          completedMatchDataArr.push(completedMatchDocData);
          resolve(completedMatchDataArr);
        });
        console.log("sarang", completedMatchDataArr[2]);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error getting documents", err);
      });
    });
}

const createNewCompletedMatchDocs = (async(change, context) => {
  let completedMatchData = await getOldCompletedMatchDocs();

  console.log('aman', completedMatchData[1]);

  const newValue = change.after.data();
  const previousValue = change.before.data();

  const st1 =newValue.status;
  const st2 = previousValue.status;
  console.log('I am a log entry' + st1 + ' ' + st2);

  var data = completedMatchData[0];

  return db.collection('Match_Creator').doc('cricket').collection('completedMatchList').add(data)
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('Error writting document: ' + error);
    return false;
  });
})

module.exports = createCompletedMatchListDoc;
```

And After copy this doc(c434108) i want to delete this doc(c434108) from path 1.

And My index.js file is:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const storeMatchData = require("./liveScoring");
const createCompletedMatchListDoc = require("./completedMatchList");

var http = require("https");

module.exports = {
  liveScoring: functions.https.onRequest(storeMatchData),
  createCompletedMatchListDoc: functions.https.onRequest(
    createCompletedMatchListDoc
  )
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to solve my problem.

This is my completeMatchList.js file

```
/* eslint-disable promise/catch-or-return */
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const { db } = require("./db/index");

const createCompletedMatchListDoc = (request, response) => {
  completedMatchDocsData();
};

function completedMatchDocsData() {
  setNewCompletedMatchDocs()
 }

function getOldCompletedMatchDocs(){

  var completedMatchesRef = db
  .collection("Match_Creator")
  .doc("cricket")
  .collection("matchList");

  var completedMatchDocData;
  var completedMatchDataArr = [];

return new Promise(resolve => {
    let query = completedMatchesRef
      .where("status", "==", "live")
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line promise/always-return
        if (snapshot.empty) {
          console.log("No matching documents.");
          return;
        }

        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          // completedMatchDocData = doc.data();
          completedMatchDocData = {
            docId: "",
            docData: ""
          } 
          completedMatchDocData.docId = doc.id;
          completedMatchDocData.docData = doc.data();

          completedMatchDataArr.push(completedMatchDocData);
          resolve(completedMatchDataArr); // Here i am getting the data and pushing it in array
        });
        console.log("sarang", completedMatchDataArr);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error getting documents", err);
      });
    });
}

const setNewCompletedMatchDocs = (async () => {
  let getCompletedMatchData = await getOldCompletedMatchDocs();
  // console.log("balram", getCompletedMatchData[0].docId);
  let newCompletedMatchDocRef = db.collection("Match_Creator").doc("cricket").collection("completedMatchList").doc(getCompletedMatchData[0].docId);
  return newCompletedMatchDocRef.set(getCompletedMatchData[0].docData); //set/copy the data to new path.
})
```

This is my main index.js file

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const storeMatchData = require("./liveScoring");
const createCompletedMatchListDoc = require("./completedMatchList");

const { db } = require("./db/index");

var http = require("https");

module.exports = {
  liveScoring: functions.https.onRequest(storeMatchData),
  createCompletedMatchListDoc: functions.https.onRequest(
    createCompletedMatchListDoc
  )
};
```

Now after copy document data to a new path i will delete the previous document. For deleting the document i have not written the function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing anything that would allow you to move a document between collections(someone correct me if I'm wrong). You have to copy from the old collection to the new one and then remove the old one.

This is another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47263246/11928097) on StackOverflow that is running into this same issue and someone provided Java code on how to implement it.

EDIT: Updated link.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i know that i cannot move document between collections. I can only copy data. The link You have provided is based on angular but i want it in javascript or nodejs

Comment: I pasted the wrong link, I updated the post with the link with Java I mentioned.

Comment: i have updated my code in my question. when i am trying to add/copy data which i am getting from getOldCompletedMatchDocs() function to new path which i am trying to do in createNewCompletedMatchDocs() functon. I am getting an error

Comment: Error which i am getting : UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'after' of undefined
>      at createNewCompletedMatchDocs (/Users/amansankrit/Desktop/predicta-function/functions/completedMatchList.js:54:27)
>      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
>  (node:3264) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise

Comment: And i have edited my code also. You can check it above

Comment: Please help me with the code for this problem.@Stefan G.

Comment: Hey I think the issue resides in getOldCompletedMatchDocs, the function is not declared as async and you are returning a promise. Here you have an explanation of unhandlepromiserejectionwarning errors like the one you are getting.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39716569/nodejs-unhandledpromiserejectionwarning

Comment: not able to solve the error. Please help @Stefan G.