# How I can copy One Firebase Collection to Another Firebase Collection in Android

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

[image]

As you can there are 3 collections in my Firestore database:

1. `Plans`
2. `UPIs`
3. `Users`

Upon Successful Signup of a user, I want to copy all the values present in Plans Collection to Users Collection under their mobile number as a document.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no straightforward solution for that. The single option that you have, is to [move each and every document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47244403/how-to-move-a-document-in-cloud-firestore) that exists in the "Plans" collection, to any other collection of your choice.

If you want the "Plans" to be a subcollection under the user's mobile number document in the "Users" collection, then you need to have a schema similar to this:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- Users (collection)
       |
       --- $phoneNumber (document) //
            |
            --- Plans (Sub-collection)
                 |
                 --- $planId
                       |
                       --- //fields
```

This operation can be done on the client, or using a trusted environment you control. The latter is obviously more recommended. So you might consider using [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/products/functions), to [trigger a function on user creation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/firebase-auth#event_types) that does exactly that.

Comment: Hey UncagedMist. Can I help you with other information?